# Decimal datatype in access with OdbcDriver

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am creating a table in access database using `OdbcConnection` class as I am using DSN but I was unable to create table. An error is generated "Syntax error in field initilizer." I am using c# 3.5.

Query which I had written for creating table is

```
create table [tblEmployee] 
(
     [ID] long not null , 
     [EmployeeSalary] decimal null
)
```

I think problem is with decimal datatype in Odbc driver but when I am using `OleDbConnection` then no problem arises.

Comment: Decimal data type is only available with ADO ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214854 , http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275561 ).

Comment: then which datatype I will use instead of decimal. Cal you please let me know available datatype for odbc.

Comment: Currency can often suit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the new datatypes by setting the appropriate connection string attribute `ExtendedAnsiSQL`.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716404(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that this will also require you to take care of other issues such as correct ANSI quoting, i.e. using single quotes for string values.